# AWS CDK NodejsFunction: import a module exported as "export ="

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, commonjs, esmodules

Is there any way to use modules (e.g. sharp) exported as `export = someModule` in a Lambda function defined using `NodejsFunction` in the `aws-cdk-lib`?
The require statement(`const xxx = require('module')`) does not seem to work with the Lambda TypeScript code that CDK bundles.

Both of the following import writing methods resulted in the error.

```js
import sharp from 'sharp'
import * as sharp from 'sharp'
import sharp = require('sharp')
```

```
Something went wrong installing the \"sharp\" module
Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'
Require stack:
- /var/task/index.js
- /var/runtime/index.mjs
```

The CDK code defines the Lambda function as follows.

```js
import { aws_lambda_nodejs as lambda } from 'aws-cdk-lib'

const fn = new lambda.NodejsFunction(scope, 'fn-id', {
  entry: 'lib/lambda/my-fn.ts',
  functionName: 'fn-name'
})
```

Comment: Is the error thrown at synth-time, deploy-time or run-time?

Comment: Run-time. No deploy errors.

Comment: I suspect this is a sharp-specific problem.  Is CDK using [esbuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html#local-bundling) or Docker for bundling?  See the [sharp installation docs](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#esbuild).

Answer (score 0):

If you're introducing `node_modules` or `external modules` for your NodejsFunction, you'll need to specify this in your CDK Stack.

Look at [bundling options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction.html#bundling) to learn more.

Here's an example that uses `externalModules`, `nodeModules` and `layers` to access resources.

```
this.lambdaFunctionExample= new NodejsFunction(this, `lambdaFunctionExample`, {
  runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
  handler: "handler",
  bundling: { minify: false, nodeModules: ["@aws-sdk/client-sfn", "axios", "axios-retry"], externalModules: ["aws-sdk", "crypto-js"] },
  layers: [lambdaLayerStack.getSecrets, lambdaLayerStack.generateMagentoAuthorisationHeader]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are building on M1 you have to install sharp via

`npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp`

otherwise you will get the following error on lambda execution:

`Could not load the \"sharp\" module using the linux-x64 runtime\`

After you installed sharp you can import it like this:

`import sharp from 'sharp' // typescript`

`const sharp = require("sharp") // javascript`

If you encounter this error on `cdk deploy`

```
[ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: asset-input/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node
```

add the following option to your `NodejsFunction` to define `sharp` as a module that should be installed instead of bundled

```
const fn = new lambda.NodejsFunction(scope, 'fn-id', {
  entry: 'lib/lambda/my-fn.ts',
  functionName: 'fn-name',
  bundling: {
    nodeModules: ['sharp'],
  }
})
```